# How to make SQLite work in Laravel

Tags: sqlite, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Whenever I run `php artisan migrate`, the following error is shown in the console:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

The *database.sqlite* file is located at *database/*. I'm running *Windows 10*, *Laravel 5.2*. Here is *.env* file config:

### **.env:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have looked everywhere, but could not find what causes this error and how to resolve it.

### Update

I managed to make migrations run successfully by replacing `DB_DATABASE=database` with `DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite` in *.env* file. However, new error occurs whenever I try to retrieve items from the database:

```
public function index()
{
    // cause of the error
    $cards = Card::all();

    return view('cards.index', compact('cards'));
}
```

The above action throws following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34:
>   Database (database/database.sqlite) does not exist.

The strange thing is, that the command `Card::all()` works flawlessly in `php artisan tinker` mode. What kind of magic is that?

Anyway, I've also found out, that the line:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

in *database.php* file needs to be replaced with just `database_path('database.sqlite')` and **everything starts to work normally**.

---

It seems, that the root of the problem is `env('DB_DATABASE')` call. I went to *SQLiteConnector.php* file and dumped the output of both `env('DB_DATABASE')` and `database_path('database.sqlite')`. Here are their outputs respectively:

```
dd(env('DB_DATABASE'))               // => 'database/database.sqlite'
dd(database_path('database.sqlite')) // => 'D:\www\project\database\database.sqlite'
```

As you see, their output differs, and the second one is what is expected. Is this a Laravel bug? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @downvoter please explain the downvote! I can't understand what I did wrong

Comment: I do not know who downvoted but valid question, and you got my vote.

Comment: replace the 'database' line in the config/database.php with the following to use relative paths:
'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'database.sqlite')),

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Short Solution

Though not answering the question, the way to fix *"Database not found"* issue is to replace the following line in *database.php*:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

with

```
'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Working with Laravel 5.2 and Windows 7 64bit. Thanks!

Comment: its worked...I'm curious to know how it works! Could you?

Comment: This is not a good solution. Just commenting out DB_DATABASE in .env file is better, isn't it?

Answer (score 23):

1. Create file called `database.sqlite` in this folder as `database/database.sqlite`
2. Open the `.env` file and change MySQL to SQLite
3. Comment password and username and databaseName using '#'
4. run **`php artisan migrate`** enjoy

env file like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

#DB_PORT=3306

#DB_DATABASE=database

#DB_USERNAME=homestead

#DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: Note: The `database.sqlite` file can be empty. Just run `touch database/database.sqlite`.

Comment: @NicoHood exactly 

Comment: should should be the correct answer here

Comment: It is no longer needed to create the `database.sqlite` file manually. When running `php artisan migrate` it will ask if `database.sqlite` should be created.

Answer (score 22):

By using the relative path, migrations will fail because they use project directory as root directory...

To correct everything, I suggest setting:

```
   DB_DATABASE=database\database.sqlite
```

and tweaking the sqlite connections in config/database.php as follows:

```
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE/..', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

## Original Answer

The .env file should contain this:

```
   DB_DATABASE=..\database\database.sqlite
```

With some testing you can verify that the link included in DB_DATABASE
is relative to the 'public' directory (at least on my Windows machine). That's why we should introduce `..\` before your link.

And of course, using an absolute link should do it too:

```
   DB_DATABASE=D:\www\project\database\database.sqlite
```

as @Josh suggests

Comment: DB_DATABASE=..\database\database.sqlite worked for me on Laravel 8

Answer (score 11):

Complementing the awnser by our friend @alexander-lomia

*Change:*

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite'))
```

*To:*

```
'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE'))
```

in **database.php**

:)

Comment: I like this way, to use relative path in .env (DB_DATABASE=database/my_file.sqlite for example), although it does not allow to set absolute path in DB_DATABASE :)

`'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'database.sqlite')),`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a relative path you need to use an absolute path in your `.env` file.

```
DB_DATABASE=/var/www/project/database/database.sqlite
```

or in your case:

```
DB_DATABASE=D:\www\project\database\database.sqlite
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem as you did. You have to use the **absolute** path in ENV file.

Please check the official documentation about this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
```

Comment: These days: simply comment out `DB_DATABASE` altogether. Laravel will use `.../database/database.sqlite` as default (and create the file at the time of `php artisan migrate`)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Laravel 5.5

1. In .env file just have the connection name and remove all other `DB_` related settings: `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_testing`
2. Define your sqlite settings in the `config/database.php` file:

   ```
   'connections' => [

       'sqlite_testing' => [
           'driver' => 'sqlite',
           'database' => database_path('testing-db.sqlite'),
           'prefix' => '',
       ],

       ...
   ]
   ```

My file is in the `database/testing-db.sqlite`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest and easiest solution is to remove default mysql settings in .env and work in database.php. That's what worked for me at least.

Remove the following...

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: What is the point in removing them? It would be much better to replace the dummy values with real ones..

Comment: If you don't remove and lets suppose try to use sqlite, laravel 5.3 still execute these strings and therefore trigger mysql error. database.php file already have variables available to define/update database.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following works rather well, if you prefer to use relative paths:

replace the 'database' line under SQLite with the following:

```
'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'database.sqlite')),
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the setting I had used,

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
],
```

I also had to run `touch database.sqlite` in the database folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `php artisan migrate` will use the `DB_DATABASE` from the root of the project, while serving the project with `php artisan serve` will run from the public directory.

The best solution for me is to create a link to database inside public directory:

- UNIX: `ln -s database public/database`
- Windows: `mklink /J public\database database`

Of course then you would have to deny access to database folder from HTTP requests but that should be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

1. Create the database file `touch database/database.sqlite`
2. Specify database in `.env` like this

```
    DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
    #DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    #DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
    #DB_USERNAME=root
    #DB_PASSWORD=
```

3. Modify `config/database.php` like this

```
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' =>  database_path(env('DB_DATABASE')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
   ...
```

4. Run the migration `php artisan migrate`

Those four steps were enough for me.

**My setup: `Windows 11, "php": "^8.1", "laravel/framework": "^10.10"`,**